# Java file read problem

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have a java problem. I am trying  to read a txt file which has a variable number of integers per line, and for each line I need to sum every second integer! I am using scanner to read integers, but can't work out when a line is done. Can anyone help pls?

Comment: Complete your question by adding your code.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the [BufferedReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) class for reading a textfile and at the [StringTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class for splitting each line into strings.

```
String input;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"));
while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
  input = input.trim();
  StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(input);
  String text = str.nextToken(); //get your integers from this string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd probably use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/). The method [`readLines(File file)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29) returns a List of Strings, one for each line. Then you can simply handle one line at a time.

Something like this:

```
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(file);
    for (String line : lines) {
        // handle one line
    }
```

<sub>(Unfortunately Commons IO doesn't support generics, so the there would be an unchecked assignment warning when assigning to List<String>. To remedy that use either @SuppressWarnings, or just an untyped List and casting to Strings.)</sub>

This is, perhaps, an example of a situation where one can apply "[know and use the libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822768/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-a-java-noob/826344#826344)" and skip writing some lower-level boilerplate code altogether.

Comment: this is at the expense of incurring the cost of including the jar lib... though i do agree if you can you should try to use public domains libraries.

Comment: Yes, if this was the *only* thing you'd need from Commons IO, perhaps it wouldn't be worth it. But typically Apache Commons libs (and e.g. Google Collections) have lots of stuff useful for your project.

Answer (score 0):

or scrape from commons the essentials to both learn good technique and skip the jar:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) 
    {

       File file = new File("Test.java"); 

       BufferedReader buffreader = null;
       String line = "";

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        try 
            {
                buffreader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file) );
                line = buffreader.readLine();
                while (line != null) 
                {
                   line = buffreader.readLine();
                   //do something with line or:
                   list.add(line);
                }
             } catch (IOException ioe) 
             {
                    // ignore
             } finally 
             {
               try 
               {
                  if (buffreader != null) 
                  {
                     buffreader.close();
                  }
               } catch (IOException ioe) 
               {
                    // ignore
               }

            }

           //do something with list
           for (String text : list) 
           {       
               // handle one line
               System.out.println(text);       
           }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution that I would use.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String nameFile;
        File file;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int total = 0;

        System.out.println("What is the name of the file");

        nameFile = keyboard.nextLine();
        file = new File(nameFile);

        if(!file.exists()){
            System.out.println("File does not exit");   
            System.exit(0);
        }


        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            String fileData = reader.nextLine();
            for(int i = 0; i < fileData.length(); i++){
                if(Character.isDigit(fileData.charAt(i))){
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(fileData.charAt(i)+"");
                }

            }
            System.out.println(total + " \n");
        }

    }

}
```