# Proper Java classes for reading and writing files?

Tags: java, file, serialization, file-io, text-files

Reading some sources about Java file I/O managing, I get to know that there are more than 1 alternative for input and output operations.

These are:

- `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`
- `FileReader` and `FileWriter`
- `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`
- `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter`
- `Scanner` class

**What of these is best alternative for text files managing? What's best alternative for serialization? What does Java NIO say about it?**

Comment: `nio` means simply "new I/O": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O

Comment: @MarkWhitaker that URL intrigues me. Is this page 1 level deeper than most wiki pages?

Comment: For the first question, BufferedReader and writer are better if you're using huge data.

Comment: The Stream ones are for binary files. The Reader and Writer are for text.

Comment: @Cruncher Yep, that's interesting.  I think that once DNS figures out the address to send the request to, the software that handles the request on the server can do anything it pleases with the rest of the URL, and perhaps their server just doesn't handle slashes in the usual way, because slashes in encyclopedia entries are too common.  There's a page for "Boeing F/A-18E/F Super Hornet", e.g.

Comment: Well, slashes as "directory separator" in URLs are purely a convention: The server can apply it or not, however it wants.

Comment: For the absolute simplest ways to do text file IO in Java, use a 3rd party library such as [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). See for example [this answer in a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908989/what-are-the-best-simplest-classes-used-for-reading-files-in-java/4909025#4909025).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Two kinds of data

Generally speaking there are two "worlds":

- binary data
- text data

When it's a file (or a socket, or a BLOB in a DB, or ...), then it's always binary data *first*.

Some of that binary data can be *treated* as text data (which involves something called an ["encoding" or "character encoding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)).

### Binary Data

Whenever you want to handle the *binary* data then you need to use the [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)/[`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) classes (generally, everything that contains `Stream` in its name).

That's why there's a [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and a [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html): those *read from* and *write to* files and they handle binary data.

### Text Data

Whenever you want to handle *text* data, then you need to use the [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html)/[`Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) classes.

Whenever you need to convert binary data to text (or vice versa), then you need some kind of encoding (common ones are UTF-8, UTF-16, ISO-8859-1 (and related ones) and the good old US-ASCII). "Luckily" the Java platform also has something called the "default platform encoding" which it will use whenever it needs one but the code doesn't specify one.

The platform default encoding is a two-sided sword, however:

- it makes writing code easier, because you don't have to specify an encoding for each operation *but*
- it might not match the data you have: If the platform-default encoding is ISO-8859-1 and the file you read is actually UTF-8, then you will get a scrambled output!

For reading, we should also mention the [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) which can be wrapped around any other `Reader` and adds the ability to handle whole lines at once.

[`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is a special class that's meant to parse text input into tokens. It's most useful for *structured text* but often used on `System.in` to provide a very simple way to read data from stdin (i.e. from what the user inputs on the keyboard).

### Bridgin the gap

Now, confusingly enough there are classes that make the bridge between those worlds, which generally have *both parts* in their names:

- an `InputStreamReader` *consumes* a `InputStream` and *is itself* a `Reader`.
- an `OutputStreamWriter` *is a* `Writer` and *writes to* an `OutputStream`.

And then there are "shortcut classes" that basically combine two other classes that are often combined.

- a `FileReader` is basically a combination of a `FileInputStream` with an `InputStreamReader`
- a `FileWriter` is basically a combination of a `FileOutputStream` with an `OutputStreamWriter`

Note that `FileReader` and `FileWriter` used to have a major drawback compared to their more complicated "hand-built" alternative: they use the platform default encoding, which might not be what you're trying to do! In Java 11 they finally got two-argument constructors so they can still be used when wanting to provide an encoding.

### What about serialization?

[`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) are special streams used for serialization.

As the name of the classes implies serializing involves only binary data (even if serializing `String` objects), so you'll want to use `*Stream` classes exclusively. As long as you avoid any `Reader`/`Writer` classes, you should be fine.

### Further resources

- [the Basic I/O trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html).
- [Joel's old-ish article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) (good introduction, slightly light on technical detail)
- [On the evils of platform default encoding](http://arnosoftwaredev.blogspot.co.at/2005/03/default-encoding-considered-harmful.html) ([also this](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/newbies.php#10))

Comment: Thanks, could you see my edits and tell me about the changes, please?

Comment: @Diego: I'm sorry but no, that changes the scope of the question quite dramatically and should *probably* be moved into a separate question.

Comment: Well so far I accept you answer. You are right though. Just I want to take my serializing alternative as good. Thanks!

Comment: @Diego: I've taken the liberty of rolling back your edit, because this way the question is more likely to be useful for future visitors. But your implementation looks good (at least from the perspective of chosing the right I/O classes, I didn't do an in-depth review).

Comment: Thanks @Joachim, I accept and agree with the point of rolling back the edit.