# Error in if statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have an android app. in that I am comparing two strings from the EditTest, but I get some strange results...

```
if(v==findViewById(R.id.submit)){
            //

            if(email==crfm_email)
            {

                String warn="Done!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), warn, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            else
            {
                oFN=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.owners_first_name);
                String warn="email addresses do not match "+eMail+" "+crfEmail;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), warn, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

            }

        }
```

the problem is that the control always goes to the else part even if the input for both variables are same.
I know that its a simple mistake but cant crack it out...!

Comment: thanks           why is this comment" "if" is not a loop.!!!! – radkrish"?

Comment: Iam confused..because I have more than one answer for this question and all are similar..which one to be accepted..the first responce..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are doing an object ref compare instead of an object compare.

```
if(email==crfm_email)
```

Should probably be...

```
if(email.equals(crfm_email))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
if (email.equals(crfm_email))
{
    ....
```

to compare the strings.  The point being you want to compare the contents of the `String`s, not the references to the `String` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
email.equals(crfm_email)
```

== in java compares if it is the same instance of the string not if the content of the string are the same

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in the following SO question: [Java common Gotcha's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169815/java-common-gotchas).

Top contender is using `==` in stead of `equals` :)