# Could JVM be smarter about sharing String data?

Tags: java, string

Take a look at this test

```
    String s1 = "1234";
    String s2 = "123";
    Field field = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    char[] value1 = (char[]) field.get(s1);
    char[] value2 = (char[]) field.get(s2);
    System.out.println(value1 == value2);
```

It prints `false` and it means that the JVM holds two different char arrays for s1 and s2. Can anybody explain the reason why s1 and s2 cannot share the same char array? It seems like java.lang.String was designed for content sharing, isn't it?

Note: I don't know about all JVMs. This is Oracle's Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 22.1-b02 (JRE 1.7).

**UPDATE**

On the other hand, if partial sharing is rare (it seems it's only for Strings created by String.substring) then why should all Strings have `int count` and `int offset` fields? It is 8 useless bytes. And this is not only the size, it is also the creation speed. The bigger the object the longer its initialization. Here's a test

```
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        new String("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0);
```

it takes ~200ms. If I use this class

```
class String2 {
    char[] value;
    String2(String2 s) {
        value = s.value;
    }
}
```

it takes ~140 ms.

Comment: Why should it be the same array? 123 and 1234 are different values.

Comment: Open java.lang.String src, you will see that String has 3 fields char[] value, int offset, int count. Thus, if there is a "1234" in the JVM string constant pool, s2 could point its value to this char array, set offset = 0; count = 3. No need for a new char array. Makes sense?

Comment: Makes sense, that would be a nice optimization in terms of memory consumption. However, when creating a new string, the JVM would have to search all string instances and try to find a substring that matches the one it's trying to allocate. That sounds like a massive overhead and IMHO outweighs the benefits you gain from pointing to the same array in memory.

Comment: Well, I intentionally made s1 and s2 start with the same characters "123". If you write a program yourself would it be any overhead if you wanted to test, before creating a new char array for s2, if there is a string starting with "123" in your pool?

Comment: Assuming you don't create any index-like structures (which would also require some memory) you would have to go through every string instance you have already allocated, so the computational complexity would be o(n^2) (number of allocated strings * number of letters in string). Not very nice.

Comment: It also requires some memory to hold "1234" and "123" as separate arrays in the pool, isn't it?

Comment: Of course, I don't question it. What I'm saying is that the time needed to find a string in memory that you could use is probably not worth the gains in terms of memory usage.

Comment: Right, it's possible, cannot count o(n^2). Just afraid someone has made a mistake...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anybody explain the reason why s1 and s2 cannot share the same char array?

They *can*, they just don't, probably because the JVM start-up time would be impacted by looking through the [string `intern` pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) for partial matches.

It's worth noting that with non-interned strings, they *can* share a char array, in certain cases:

```
String s1 = "1234";
String s2 = s1.substring(0, 3);
```

...at least through OpenJDK 6. Apparently, in [OpenJDK7 they don't share anymore](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) *(thank you [Marko Topolnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik) for teaching me that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13803521/157247))*.

And interestingly, Sun's JVM 1.6 separates them if you intern:

```
String s1 = "1234";
String s2 = s1.substring(0, 3);
Field field = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
field.setAccessible(true);
char[] value1 = (char[]) field.get(s1);
char[] value2 = (char[]) field.get(s2);
System.out.println(value1 == value2);
s2 = s2.intern();
value2 = (char[]) field.get(s2);
System.out.println(value1 == value2);
```

I get:

```
true
false
```

I guess it doesn't like having strings in the intern pool that are subsets of other strings.

Comment: +1. Also worth mentioning, for string literals only - it can be done by a compiler, the jvm doesn't even need to know about this optimization.

Comment: I intentionally took the simplest case when both s1 and s2 start with the same characters "123". I cannot belive that there can be any start-up time impact in this situation.

Comment: @amit: Interning is done by the JVM, not by the compiler. But yes, the compiler could emit code turning Evgeniy's `String s2 = "123";` into `String s2 = s1.substring(0, 3);` instead, but I can't imagine it would be a good idea.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev, The class file format defines string constants using the [CONSTANT_Utf8_info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html) struct.  The length immediately precedes the byte array in the class file, so two strings, one of which is a substring of another, cannot be combined by the class file generator.  Doing prefix checks when converting from UTF8 to UTF16 would require building and walking a trie so there would be some start-up time impact.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, an especially bad idea when your JVM allows people to mutate backing arrays via `Field.setAccessible`.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anybody explain the reason why s1 and s2 cannot share the same char array?

Because `"1234"` is not the same sequence of characters as `"123"`.

Comment: But AFAIK `"1234".substring(0,2)` might actually do use the same `char[]`. Won't it? (**EDIT:** Tested, it does use the same `char[]`, even though it is not the same sequence. It uses the `size` and `offset` variables for it).

Comment: `#substring()` calls _can_ reference the same `char[]` as `this` but there's no guarantee that it will. But the OP's code does not include a `#substring()` call.

Comment: But in some cases, it actually does.Thus, I do not understand why the fact that "1234" is not the same char sequence as "123" is an answer to this question, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

My take is the reason that JVMs don't go to that length in interning the strings is that it is simply not worth it:

A naive implementation of interning that *minimized* the usage of space as you propose would have `O(N^2)` performance where `N` is the number of characters of unique string data that is interned in the lifetime of the JVM.  (OK, it is a bit more complicated than that ... but it is *expensive*.)

An implementation that attempted to avoid the `O(N^2)` problem would *typically* end up using more space to avoid the problem than is saved by sharing character arrays.

The String implementation (including interning) is a pragmatic implementation that balances the competing concerns to give the best performance when averaged over a range of real-world applications.